# Why the local variable value is not visible after iterating RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am writing code in scala for apache-spark.
my local  variable "country" value is not reflecting after rdd iteration done.
I am assigning value in country variable after checking condition inside rdd iteration.until rdd is iterating value is available in country variable after control come out from loop value lost.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.lang.Long

object KPI1 {

  def main(args:Array[String]){
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\shivam docs\\hadoop-2.6.5.tar\\hadoop-2.6.5");

    val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("KPI1").master("local").getOrCreate();
    val textFile=spark.read.textFile("C:\\shivam docs\\HADOOP\\sample data\\wbi.txt").rdd;

    val splitData=textFile.map{
      line=>{
        val token=line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        (token(0),token(10).replace("\"","").replace(",", ""));
      }
    };

   // splitData.max()._2;
   var maxele=0l;
    var index=0;
    var country="";
    splitData.foreach(println);
    for(ele<-splitData){
      val data=Long.parseLong(ele._2);
      if(maxele<data){
        maxele=data;
        println(maxele);
        country=ele._1;
        println(country);
      }
    };
println("***************************** "+country+maxele);

spark.close()
  }
}
```

country variable value should not have default value.

Answer (score 0):

Both `for` and `foreach` is wide operation. That means the execution will happen on more than one executors and that's why you are getting default value for some threads. I'm running my sample code in *single node cluster with 4 executors* and you can see the execution has happened in two different executors( Thread id is evident)

**Sample**

```
val baseRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)))

for (h <- baseRdd) {
  println( "Thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getId)
  println("Value "+ h)
}
```

**Output**

```
Thread id 48
Value (1,2)
Thread id 50
Value (3,4)
```

If you still want to have your expected result, follow either of the below option

1.Make changes to your spark context configuration as 
    `master("local[1]")`. This will run your job with single executor.

2. `collect()` your `splitData` before you perform `for(ele<-splitData){...}`

**Note** Both the options are strictly for testing or experimental purpose only and it will not work against large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using variables within Executors, Spark (YARN/Mesos etc.) creates a new instance of it per each Executor. This is why you don't see any update to your variable (the updates occur only on the Executors, none is retrieved to the Driver). If you want to accomplish this, you should use Accumulators:

Both 'maxele' & 'country' should be Accumulators.

You can read about it [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/spark-accumulators-explained) and [here](https://medium.com/@shrechak/leveraging-custom-accumulators-in-apache-spark-2-0-f4fef23f19f1)